# How to reuse example from another definition in swagger?

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a definition of a **report** object. I have another definition of **reports** object that has an array of **report** objects (via a $ref).

In the **report** definition, I have an example defined, which works fine in swagger UI.

In the **reports** definition, I want it to use the example from the *report* definition.

How can I do this? I've tried several things using $ref, the closest I got was what I have in the following YAML...

```
definitions:
  report:
    type: object
    properties:
      ID:
        type: number
        format: int
        description: "DB record ID of the report."
        readOnly: true
      ErrorContent:
        type: string
        description: "The actual problem or error infomation for this report. This can be exception stack, etc."
        readOnly: true
      UserComments:
        type: string
        description: "Any user comments collected by the app and submitted with the report."
        readOnly: true
      ReportedBy:
        type: string
        description: "The person using the app when it triggered the error this report is for."
        readOnly: true
      ReportedDateTime:
        type: string
        description: "The date/time the report was submitted."
        readOnly: true
    required:
      - ID
      - ErrorContent
      - ErrorType
      - UserComments
      - ReportedBy
      - ReportedDateTime
    example:
      ID: 11367
      ErrorContent: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."
      ErrorType: "Exception"
      UserComments: "Was clicking this and that and then Boom!"
      ReportedBy: "domain\\name"
      ReportedDateTime: "2016-01-19 14:07:00"
  reports:
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
      reports:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/report'
    example:
      message: "success"
      reports:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/report'
```

However, in Swagger UI, the above results in...

```
{
  "message": "success",
  "reports": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/report"
    }
  ]
}
```

One interesting note, in Swagger UI, when I look at the model view, it does have all of **report** even with descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is correct--the `examples` section cannot be referenced with a JSON pointer.  See the [OAI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) for what is currently supported.

If you feel this is a common use case, please open an issue on the spec repository.

Comment: Thanks! I'll open a bug. Without this change, I have to duplicate examples in multiple places.